# Intercept and filter incoming packets at run time in Tigase (XMPP)

Tags: xmpp, tigase

I am using **Tigase**(XMPP) server. I want to block every incoming message from a particular JID. At the moment i am blocking a particular JID by dropping it's packet in *Message.java* inside

```
/tigase/xmpp/impl
```

package. Is it the right way to do this, if not please guide me.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An advantage of blocking messages in Message plugin is that the performance penalty for this filtering is reduced to minimal. However there are quite a few disadvantages of doing it this way:

- You modify Tigase's code which makes you version update painful and time consuming
- It does not allow you to filter out any other packets (such as presence or iq)
- Even if you block messages in Message plugin this message may still be processed by other plugins which intercept messages (such as offline message, message archiver, etc...)

Now, what is the best way to implement such a filtering it depends on what you really want to do and why do you want to do it. Have you heard of privacy lists? Please take a look at it. Tigase fully implements privacy lists, why you do not want to use them? Why you cannot use them?

Usually such a filtering you speak about is done in the Tigase filter called preprocessor. Please take a look at the privacy lists plugin or domain filter for a code example.